# Line gets drawn only after Control moves over it

Tags: c#, .net

I have a set of custom controls and a list of geometric objects that I need to draw on the same handle.

I override the `OnPaint` procedure, put the `base.OnPaint(e)` in the first line and commence with the drawing of the geometric objects (via `e.Graphics.DrawLine` etc.).
Those are in a locked list and *decay* after a while.
Also the customized controls can move around the window.

Now this is almost working as intended except for this fun fact:

The geometric shapes appear **only after** a control is moved along/above their layouts.

I was able to reproduce this in a small environment: [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/CuD6yz5Y)

I tried flushing the graphics object; save/restore; changing Clip.
Nothing seemed to work.

I am guessing that regions only get invalidated and repainted once a control is present. But how can I force them to be drawn anyways?

Comment: You might be looking for [Control.Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx) or [UIElement.InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) depending on whether you are Winforms or WPF.

Comment: Oh. Now I feel stupid XD. I thought `Control.Invalidate` will only trigger repainting of Control paint jobs. So I didn't even consider it. Well it did the trick. Make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control.Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will tell the framework that the control needs to be redrawn. It does this automatically to redraw controls after, for example, the mouse has obscured part of it, but it will only redraw a the small section that the mouse covered (hence why you end up with a "(re)painting with the mouse" effect. Also moving a window will force it to redraw, as does covering it with another window and then moving that window away again.

But if you are doing a bunch of custom painting, you need to let it know that the control needs to be redrawn by calling `Invalidate` yourself.